# on long click listener ListActivity class

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I have an app which use ListView,I have set onListItemClick event to view details about contact,and I want to implement onLongListItemClick to show a dialog and I don't know why it doesn't work,I mean nothing happens,I tried like this:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
{   
    //code
}

public void onLongListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
{   
    showdialog();
}
```

Comment: How do you add your listener ? Do you pass in the onLongListItemClick method ?

Comment: it is in the class that extends ListActivity and onListItemClick works fine

Comment: still, How do you register your listener ?

Comment: I mean do you do something like listView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){})

Comment: print some log as first line of onLongListItemClick method, and see if this method is getting exectued or not.

Comment: Try to use the showdialog method inside the onListItemClick method, just to make sure that the issue is not from the showdialog method (assuming that the onListItemClick method is working fine as you said).

Comment: Have you done somthing like `listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(myLongClickListner);` ???

Comment: showdialog () is ok I tried with OnItemClick and it works

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try like this :

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long Clicked : ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
});
```

You need to add `return true;` here otherwise it will transfer control to single click event listener once you release your touch.

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: i am new,i have to have 15 reputation :)

Comment: I would put the implementation of the listener in a private inner class.  This better encapsulates the code handling it.  For example:
    getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new LongOnItemClickHandler());