# Set long click listener for listview

Tags: android, listview, listener, long-click

I have below codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity { 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}   
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
}}
```

I need to change this to **onListItemLongClick()** but how? Is it possible?

Comment: Could you try explaining what you want to do in a different way, with more detail? Your example code doesn't seem to accomplish anything, so it's hard to guess...

Comment: I need a function that when i click long time (like 2 second) on an item in listview then my other codes in function execute.

Comment: have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846707/how-to-implement-a-long-click-listener-on-a-listview ?

Comment: Yeah i saw this but i need to do that as a function.watch my example function. I need exactly like that but with longclick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855903/on-long-click-listener-listactivity-class), but it looks like it's not an exact duplicate.

What you've noticed is that the [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) class does not have a method override specifically for this case.

In order to add this functionality as a method override, your class should implement the `AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener` interface, and then you can add the `onItemLongClick()` method override, which acts just as the `onListItemClick()` method override you already have, but responds to long clicks.

Just make sure that you follow instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846707/how-to-implement-a-long-click-listener-on-a-listview/8846824#8846824), you must use `android:longClickable="true"` in the layout xml, or call `listview.setLongClickable(true);`

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {

    ListView listview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        listview.setLongClickable(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v,
                                   final int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "long clicked pos: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Toast.makeText(this, "short clicked pos: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

    }

 //....................
```

Answer (score 3):

you can simply do it with `setOnItemLongClickListener`

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(ClassName.class, "Long Clicked Trigger: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                int index, long arg3) {

             // write your code

            return false;
        }});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the listener, then the callback would appear as a function (method) in your class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements View.OnLongClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // Do your work here
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

yes it is possible and quite easy to achieve, 
simply you have to make the instance of the listview like

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
lv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View 
                    // your code here
                    return true;
                }

        });)
```

in your case instead of extending ListActivity you can make a list view in xml and find the view in MainActivity and follow the above step.